# Matrices of the form $A^k = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. Choose the correct option.

a) if $A^2 =0$ then $A$ is diagonalisable.

b) if $A^2 =I$ then $A$ is diagonalisable.

c) if $A^2 - A =0$ then $A$ is diagonalisable.

Now... for a) I tried by transforming them using minimal polynomial (cayley Hamilton) so it should satisfy $t^2 =0$ hence the eigen values are $0$ (twice) hence its not convertible and not diagonalisable... similar arguments for b) and c).

But I am not sure whether I am right... please guide me..

Comment: yes if minimal polynomial has distinct roots..then $T$ is diagonalisable

Comment: Diagonalizable in $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Bbb{C}$ ? (or another field ?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For a) : if $A^2=0$ then $A$ is nilpotent and hence isn't diagonalizable, unless it's the null matrix
- For b) : $A$ is the root of a polynomial($X^2-1$) with distinct roots and hence is diagonalizable
- For c) : $A$ is the root of a polynomial ($X^2-X$) with distinct roots and hence is diagonalizable

Comment: For b, this is true if the characteristic of the field is not 2, which might or might not be assumed in that context.

Comment: The zero matrix is diagonalizable

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Ah right, but that's a very special case. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $p(A) = 0$, then the *minimal* polynomial of $A$ divides $p(t)$.  $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial is the product of distinct linear factors (so, for example: if $A$ has minimal polynomial $t^2$ it is *not* diagonalizable, but if it has minimal polynomial $t$ then it is).

Answer (score 1):

For (c), it is an idempotent matrix, and idempotent matrices are always diagonalizable.

Answer (score 1):

One simple proof for $A^2=0$

Let $A^2=0$. if $A$ is diagonalisable Then $A=PDP^{-1}$ for some invertible $P$
$$ A^2=0\implies PD^2P^{-1}=0\implies D^2=0 \implies D=0\implies A=0 $$

Comment: What are you proving for $A^2 = 0$?  That if $A^2 = 0$, $A = 0$?

Comment: yes i was proving that if $A^2=0$ and $A$ is diagonalizable , then $A=0$

Comment: All right. Do you see that this fails to answer the question?

Comment: But it gives answer for part (a)...

Comment: It does not. In fact, $A$ isn't necessarily diagonalizable.

Comment: that's what I proved that if $A^2=0$ , then $A$ is not diagonalizable unless $A=0$

Comment: I would say that it is a challenging observation that a nilpotent matrix besides $0$ *exists* at all. Now I see that your answer isn't really *wrong*, but I feel it is somewhat misleading because of the way in which it is written.  In particular, its emphasis on the diagonalizable case (for the sake of your proof by contrapositive) makes it seem (at first) like you're showing $A$ to be diagonalizable.

Comment: But that could just be my bizarre point of view on this